# Variance of uniform distribution having an extra $2$ term

Tags: probability, variance

For $X \sim U(a,b)$, $V(X) = \frac{(b-a)^2}{12}$, but I have seen some sources have it as $\frac{1}{12}(b-a)(b-a+2)$. In fact, a question simply asked me to prove the that variance is $\frac{1}{12}(b-a)(b-a+2)$ given the uniform distribution.

I am able to successfully prove it to be $\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}$ but I'm not sure where that $2$ term can come from. When I look online, I actually see BOTH these on google images, but no explanation of the difference.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is between two different distributions

1.

$$X\sim U(a,b)$$

2.

$$Y\sim U\{a;b\}$$

1. is a continuous distribution and its variance is $\mathbb{V}[X]=\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}$
2. is a discrete distribution with variance $\mathbb{V}[Y]=\frac{n^2-1}{12}=\frac{(b-a)(b-a+2)}{12}$

---

If you want to prove $V(Y)$ the easiest way is to consider a shifted rv

$$Y\sim U\{1;n\}$$

and calculate

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} i=\frac{n+1}{2}$$

$$\mathbb{E}[Y^2]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2=\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

and thus

$$\mathbb{V}[Y]=\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^2=\dots=\frac{n^2-1}{12}$$

this is enough for your proof being

$$n=b-a+1$$

and thus

$$n^2-1=(b-a)(b-a+2)$$

Comment: how did you prove $E(X)$? I did it by integrating $\int_a^b x\frac{1}{b-a}dx$ but as you said, the variance should be discrete so how do I consider the sum to prove the same thing?

Comment: OH I see what you did. Why does a simple shift make it valid?

Comment: @user71207 : because $V(X+a)=V(X)$

Comment: Wait... but isn't this using the CONTINUOUS distribution and simply shifting it? How is THAT still valid if we are to prove for the discrete case?

Comment: @user71207 : a shift does  not affect the variance of a rv. This is always valid and it is very easy to prove. By the way did you forget to accept my answer?

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the two formulas arises because one is the variance of the **continuous** uniform distribution on the interval $[a,b]$, and the other is the variance of the **discrete** uniform distribution on the set $\{a, a+1, \ldots, b-1, b\}$.